# how to make a python file run without py extension

Tags: python, executable

I had a small python script that takes input from the command line arguments and done some
operations using the inputs taken and display the result

Below is the working example code

**some_file.py**

```
import sys

arguments = sys.argv
first_name  = sys.argv[1]
second_name = sys.argv[2]

print "Hello {0} {1} !!!!".format(first_name,second_name)
```

Now i am executing this as

```
python some_file.py Steve jobs
```

**Result :**

```
Hello Steve Jobs !!!!
```

Now what all i want is, i don't want to use python command before file name and extension of python file name, that is i want to run the file as a command tool as below

```
some_file  Steve Jobs
```

so what to do in order to run the python file as above ?

Answer (score 7):

Unix-like OS solution: the first line of the file should be `#!/usr/bin/python` (or wherever the python interpreter is) and `chmod u+x` the script. Run it with `./some_file parameters`.

If you want to launch it with `some_file parameters` simply make a link to the script in a directory which is already included into your PATH: `sudo ln -s some_file /usr/bin`.

So, here's the full procedure:

```
blackbear@blackbear-laptop:~$ cat > hw
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Hello World!"

blackbear@blackbear-laptop:~$ chmod u+x hw
blackbear@blackbear-laptop:~$ sudo ln -s hw /usr/bin
blackbear@blackbear-laptop:~$ hw
Hello World!
blackbear@blackbear-laptop:~$
```

Comment: Exactly i had added path at the start of the script and made it executable with chmod u +x. and after that when i run liek above it displayed ""bash: ./some_file: No such file or directory""

Comment: The shebang line must contain the full path to the Python interpreter, or a program of known path that will find it, such as `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Also, the shebang-based solutions will work only on Unix-like OS-es, not on Windows.

Comment: Also i dont want to use even "./" before some_file, i want to use it as a tool for example if type top in linux it will show some details right, i mean that

Comment: chmod u+x some_file    no space between 'u' and '+'

Comment: to avoid the "./" you would need to add the directory containing the file to your search path $PATH

Comment: k what i had done is created a .pth file in site directories and given the directory path in it, but still it snot working, so can u please point me in to the right  direction ?

Comment: oh its really wierd, i performed the same steps as above, but still its complaining as ""hw: command not found ""

Comment: @shivakrishna does the link (i.e. /usr/bin/hw) exist?

Answer (score 6):

make a symbolic link

```
ln -s some_file.py some_file
```

now you can type your cmd like this:

```
some_file Steve Jobs
```

Comment: but i think this is temporary solution, because if we copy the file at some other location then i hope we need to run the above command in order to run the file without py extension right ?. what i am searching and talking about is it doesn't wherever the py file exists, but when we run the file like some_file(without extension) it should work

Comment: so if we place the file permanently in python path whether we able to access the file in the above manner ?

Comment: if u r using Linux, create a file `emacs -nw some_file`, add this at the beginning `#!/bin/env python`, and `chmod +x some_file`, run it! I just tried, it works.

Comment: i think it doesn't work on bash shell, any idea how would that work on OS x in bash shell?

Comment: The link works fine in Bash whether on Linux or MacOS. However, you may have to mark the original file as executable: `chmod +x some_file.py`. Also, if the link is not in a directory in your path you may have to specify a path to it, e.g., `./some_file` if the link is in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can run the same program in python shell by using `execfile('path')`.