# Running a Python program from the command line using only the program name

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting

I'm being asked to make a python program that parses tokens.

The usage is as follows:

`$ cat input.txt | program "some text %{0} and %{1S3}" > output.txt`

but the best I can manage is:

`$ cat input.txt | py program.py "some text %{0} and %{1S3}" > output.txt`

or if I make the script executable, remove the file extension, and I'm in the current directory

`$ cat input.txt | ./program "some text %{0} and %{1S3}" > output.txt`

Is there a way for me to use the first example's style of execution with a python script? Ideally I'd also be able to use it from anywhere, not necessary when pointing at the directory containing the program.

Edit: I've tried this:

Here's what I tried --

```
$ cd projects/token_parser/
$ ln -s grap /usr/local/bin/grap
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/grap': Permission denied
$ sudo ln -s grap /usr/local/bin/grap 
[sudo] password for fosssaintdross: 
$ grap
bash: grap: command not found
```

Comment: why don't you just read and write file from your python script ?

Comment: It's a code audition for an interview so I'm trying to match their spec as closely as possible.

Comment: hint: `PATH`...

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17592462/5014455) answer

Comment: I wouldn't worry about being too picky for someone who uses `cat input.txt | program ...` as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the location containing `program.py` is in the `PATH` environment variable. Alternatively you can link to it from a path that is already in the list, for example:

```
ln -s /path/to/program.py /usr/local/bin/program
```

Comment: If you actually have write access to `/usr/local`, it's typically a far better idea to do a proper installation, rather than throwing arbitrary symlinks in to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I've added some more info.

Comment: Try linking to the full path

Comment: Do these links persist between sessions? Or is it transient?

Comment: It's persistent as your filesystem. So for a regular laptop/desktop installation the answer is yes.