# Is it possible run a python file with just its name (without python keyword and .py extension and ./name)?

Tags: python

I had a python file named abc.py which accepts two command line arguments. To run the the code I will have to type

```
python abc.py 3 5
```

But I want something like this (neither the python keyword nor the python extension),

```
abc 3 5
```

Note: I don't want to run like this - `./abc`.
This question has already been asked in [how to make a python file run without py extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592394/how-to-make-a-python-file-run-without-py-extension) but I cant find any helpful answer. Could someone help me ?

Comment: This might be possible, but the solution depends on the operating system and the shell which you are using.

Comment: After having looked into the question you linked, I fail to see why the answers don't apply to you, can you explain what other issue is there that is not covered?

Comment: @Alex, Im using mac OS and bash shell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a python file run without py extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592394/how-to-make-a-python-file-run-without-py-extension)

Comment: the `./abc` problem relates to the PATH, *If you are using custom scripts regularly you may want to make sure the directory you store them is added to the PATH environment variable.* [see details in answer to "Running python script from terminal without .py extension" on another SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27795/406941)